# Why does static make it error when trying to update textbox text

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got the following code. 
It's a form with a single textbox on it.
If I make `myTimer_Tick`not static then it works fine - why?

```
namespace Ariport_Parking
{
  public partial class AirportParking : Form
  {

    //instance variables of the form
    static Timer myTimer;


    public AirportParking()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        keepingTime(5000);
        txtMessage.Text = "hello";
    }

    //method for keeping time
    public void keepingTime(int howlong) {

        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.Enabled = true;
        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
        myTimer.Interval = howlong;

        myTimer.Start();

    }

    static void myTimer_Tick(Object myObject,EventArgs myEventArgs){
        myTimer.Stop();
        txtMessage.Text = "hello world";
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: first tell us why you want it to be static?

Comment: what doesn't work if *it is* a static ?

Comment: txtMessage gets underlined and the error is "an object is required for a non-static field". I believe Arif has answered my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the Error would be that its not able to access txtMessage.
txtMessage is an instance variable declared on the form, a Static Method does not have access to the instance data of a form.
And you can google to know why.

Comment: I'm new to c# and did not realise that the objects on a winform are effectively instance variables - that explains things.

Comment: @Reniuz I'd been looking for information and gone [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx) and copied the qualifiers for the event _TimerEventProcessor_ in the example. A little knowledge is dangerous.

Comment: @whytheq next time it would be good if you mention that in your question ;)

Comment: @Renuiz how come it's static in the example?

Answer (score 1):

Because the txtMessage is not static it need the instance of the class in order to be accessed. You don't need to make your myTimer_Tick and timer static. Or for good use lambda instead of myTimer_Tick.

instead of:

```
myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
```

use

```
myTimer.Tick += (sender, e) => { 
    myTimer.Stop();
    txtMessage.Text = "hello world";
};
```

Comment: _Or for good use lambda instead of myTimer_Tick._ what does this mean?

Comment: I assume the operator `=>` is the lambda ?

Comment: I've seen this syntax `myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);` in lots of places ......are you saying it's not the best syntax? or are there situations when I should use the traditional syntax and other situations that suit the lambda syntax?

Comment: A whole this construction (sender, e) => {}; is a lambda just take a look on documentation.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: Yes consider that you need to pass some local variables to your callback what will you do without lambda?? You will put them as a member variables right? That's not good because it complicates the logic with a lambda you could use them directly. Also consider that you will create a lot of private methods just only for the callbacks that's bad too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10000/discussion-between-alextheo-and-whytheq)